# How many cabin crews are needed for an A350-1000?

Tags: commercial-aviation, flight-attendant, airbus-a350

How many cabin crews are needed for an A350-1000?

Comment: crews, one, as always. are you asking about crew members?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends where you are flying, i.e. which countries rules apply. In the US for example, the minimum cabin crew is determined by the seating capacity:

> For airplanes having a seating capacity of more than 100 passengers—two flight attendants plus one additional flight attendant for each unit (or part of a unit) of 50 passenger seats above a seating capacity of 100 passengers.

<sup>([CFR 121.391 (a) (4)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?mc=true&n=sp14.3.121.m&r=SUBPART&ty=HTML#se14.3.121_1391))</sup>

The A350-1000 can seat up to 480 passengers, which would then require **10 flight attendants**. Typical seating is however only 369 according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A350_XWB#Specifications), which would only require **8 flight attendants**.

In Europe, EASA defines the minimum number of cabin crew in the Type Certificate Data Sheet (TCDS):

> For the A350-1000, the minimum required cabin crew number established during the aircraft
>   certification process is 8, irrespective of the Maximum Operational Passenger Seating Capacity
>   (MOPSC).
>
> [...]
>
> In accordance with the operational requirement ORO.CC.100-Number and composition of cabin
>   crew, if the MOPSC for the specific aircraft exceeds 400, the minimum required cabin crew number
>   becomes 9.

<sup>([EASA A350 TCDS](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/TCDS_EASA%20_A_151_Airbus350_Iss22-2019-11-27.pdf))</sup>

So here **8 or 9 flight attendants** are required, also depending on the seating capacity.

Comment: WOW thank you very much

Comment: Hello @MohammadGohardoust: Instead of thank you comments, consider pressing the upvote button (⯅) for usefulness, and the check mark (✓) for helping solving the issue.

Comment: What about the A350-900? Also most airlines put more flight attendants in because of the different classes. Sure by law it may be by capacity, but in an airline's perspective, that's not the case.

Comment: @AirCanada001 Typical seating for the -900 is 315, so 7 flight attendants would be enough in the US, but EASA still requires 8: "For the A350-900, the minimum required cabin crew number established during the aircraft
certification process is 8 (2 per exit pair)". Of course airlines can use more flight attendants, these are just the minimums for safety reasons, especially during an emergency evacuation.

Comment: @Bianfable: OK, thank's for the answer, you provided much more clarity.